# Android WebView not displaying when data size is increased beyond 5100 characters

Tags: java, android, webview, loaddata

I have a WebView in which I wish to render some content. But this WebView does not show a single character if the length of data I am showing reaches close to 5100 characters.

The WebView works perfectly fine if the length of data is less than 5000 characters.

I have tried to just pass simple data in the WebView similar to "abcde ....." 
with < 5000 chars it would work fine.
with > 5100 chars it won't display a single character.

I have searched through the Internet to see if there are any limits for the amount of data that can be shown inside the WebView, but I don't seem to find anything.

Here is my Java Code.

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.passage);

String data = "abcde ......."; // large number of characters > 5100.

myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(URL, data, "text/html", null,null);
```

I have tried `myWebView.loadData(data, "text/html", null);` as well instead of using the `loadDataWithBaseURL` function, but that has not helped.

Here is the XML that I am using.

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/passage"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="18px" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/passage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:layerType="software"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Please help.

EDIT : To be more precise, if I render 5096 characters, it renders properly. If 5097 or more characters are attempted to be rendered, then nothing gets displayed. If I try to log the `data` variable in a file. All data gets logged, so its not a issue relating to proper data not being saved into string.

Comment: Ideally it should work. When you open the activity having that webview, wait a while. It will load the data.

Comment: It did not load the data. I have kept the device for a fairly long time. There was a precise number of characters that it would display successfully. 'N' chars and it would display successfully without taking even a fraction of second. 'N+1' chars and it won't display a single character on the screen, no matter how much time I wait for it. :(

Comment: @Manu Device name and which OS version is it running?

Comment: @MorrisonChang ..  Device Name : Karbonn Smart Tab 10. Android Version : 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

This was happening for me but at a much lower WebView content size. Loading 1506 characters via `loadDataWithBaseURL` worked just fine but when loading 1507 characters the entire WebView disappeared, including the background. (Yet I could still copy text from it.)

The workaround was to remove `android:layerType="software"` and fall back to the default hardware layerType.

Comment: Any particular reasons for such behaviour?